# What are these small flies in my apartment?

Tags: pest-control, pest

I've been having a problem with flies in my apartment that I can't get rid of. They look like fruit flies from, and behave like them too. They are attracted to food and definitely are too small and slow to be a house fly. I have tried the normal trap of apple cider vinegar and some dish soap, but after three attempts I have yet to get rid of them. They aren't even attracted to the trap because there are never any flies in the solution.

What are these flies and what else can I try to get rid of them?

EDIT: apparently they were fruit flies... Or some other fly that is attracted to apple cider vinegar. The last few times I have tried this the traps have been completely empty, but now all of a sudden it is full of flies. Confusing, but I'm glad it's finally working.

Comment: Perhaps a picture and the Biology Stack...

Comment: Seal up your food. Remove trash in a timely manner. Bugs go away.

Comment: They kind of sound like drain flies to me. These things gather in clumps hanging from the underside of the grills and other structures. You should canvass your neighbors to see if they have similar issues. If so then then the apartment manager needs to be involved. If it is just your apartment, there are several DIY products available.

Comment: Do you have indoor potted plants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fly-like insects that are persistent, smaller, with slower reactions sound like drain flies.

Have you tried disassembling and cleaning out your kitchen sink trap? The congealed food waste there is one of the most common sources of origin for these pests.

Comment: Drain flies can be found in just abut any drain, even one not inside your apartment.

Comment: This answer can be improved - drain flies can use your home's sewer system to travel throughout your home and even from house to house. They will enter any food container that is not tightly sealed and can even survive being shut in the fridge. A clean drain is just the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem with small flies too.  We get them whenever we buy bananas.  The flies are sometimes referred to as fruit flies.  The apple cider vinegar and dish soap solution works for me.  I place a small glass with the mixture on the inside of a window sill.  The flies usually fly toward the sunlight coming through window and they are attracted to the mixture.  A couple of weeks ago, there were 20+ dead flies in the glass.  No flies have been noticed since then.  Nash Stephens

Comment: In a particularly bad infestation, I spent a day waving a vacuum hose around the kitchen to actively reduce the population. Inelegant but, together with a sticky window trap, it worked.